# Need help titling my book?

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy, titles, young-adult

So... I'm writing a book that takes place in an alternate world. In this world, there are a bunch of islands that align with the star sign constellations (Ex: Gemini, Sagittarius, etc.) the island Scorpio is known for being criminally populated and basically the "evil" island. On Scorpio lives the notorious Ravana family, who have been training their eldest daughter, Lyrin to become an alchemist where she will one day collect a sacred object from each of the islands in order to cast a spell that will brainwash all the other islands, allowing Scorpio to take control. Once she is of age and her training is complete, she sets off on her mission to find these sacred objects, sailing dangerous seas W full of dangerous creatures and venturing to islands she has never before experienced. During this journey, she meets a boy (another alchemist) from the island of Capricorn. (I'm not sure how they will meet: any ideas on that?) and she enlists his help in finding the objects, never letting him know what she plans to do with them. Eventually they start to fall in love which complicates things. Any title ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably a "what to write" question, which is not allowed on the site. I can't start a chat with you. Let me know if you wanna exchange contact information.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. As storbror notes, this is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a discussion board or workshop. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions we answer.

Comment: I suggest checking out this other question: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/how-to-come-up-with-a-good-title

Comment: Thank you Sara - Now I'm doubting my own title, see: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/27255/a-different-question-regarding-titling-a-novel

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

You are targeting a young audience, so perhaps they should be the source of your title inspiration.  Every generation distinguishes itself from its predecessors by applying their own style and slang to our shared language.  You are likely to find a relatively unused and target-age specific title just by have a few minute conversation with a few of your future readers.

And you might get some beta readers out of the deal as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds interesting - Welcome to the site also!

If you want I'll help you brainstorm in general - You appear to seek general ideas?

"**Written in the stars**" comes to mind, but I find that quite cliché..

Maybe something that connects the heritage of the family to the theme?

"**Lyrin and the path of constellations**" maybe?

"**Constellation Islands**" sounds cool/magical and somewhat spooky to me.

Edit: More ideas

"**Path of Constellations**"

"**Lyrin's Heritage**"

or Perhaps: "**Lyrin Ravana (of Scorpio)**"

Answer (score 0):

> Lyrin's Sign

comes to mind.

How about

> Star Crossed?